# Xamarin.Forms how to bind data in code to swipe view (working in xaml)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a swipeview from xml like this:

```
                    </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
                    <swipecardview:swipecardview.itemssource>
                        <x:array type="{x:type x:string}">
                            <x:string>card 1</x:string>
                            <x:string>card 2</x:string>
                            <x:string>card 3</x:string>
                            <x:string>card 4</x:string>
                            <x:string>card 5</x:string>
                            <x:string>card 6</x:string>
                        </x:array>
                    </swipecardview:swipecardview.itemssource>
                </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView>
```

If I add this to the xaml, I get 6 elements, all showing my layout (which is good).

But I need to be able to set the amount of layouts programatically.

How do I bind it like it is done here only from code?
(Sorry, I am very new to this...)

: This is the full layout:

```
                <swipeCardView:SwipeCardView 
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CardItems}"
                Grid.Column="1"                
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <!--Content of Swipe. Just remove wrapping to get layout to render-->
                            <Grid RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="White">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                <!--Titel-->
                                <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="White">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                    <Label
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             FontFamily="arial"
                             TextColor="#272727"
                             Text="Anzeigentitel" 
                              FontAttributes="Bold"
                             FontSize="20"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                             VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                                </Grid>

                                <!--Beschreibung-->
                                <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="White">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 FontFamily="arial"
                                 TextColor="#272727"
                                 HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                 Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores." 
                                 FontSize="12"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </Grid>

                                <!--Bottom-->
                                <Grid Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="White">



                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1.4*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 FontFamily="arial"
                                 TextColor="#272727"
                                 Text="id #00000000" 
                                 FontSize="10"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                        <Label
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     FontFamily="arial"
                                     TextColor="#272727"
                                     Text="99" 
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     FontSize="9"
                                     HorizontalOptions="Start" />



                                        <ImageButton
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                                   BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                                   Source="btn_star_small.png" VerticalOptions="Center" />



                                    </Grid>

                                </Grid>




                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: you can just assign the `ItemsSource` in code, or bind it to a model

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just assign the `ItemsSource` in code, or bind it to a model

```
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
mySwipeView.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: That was rediculously easly. THANK YOU!

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please do not forget to mark it, it will help others who have similar issues.